# CakePHP - how to handle double quote in conditions array

Tags: cakephp

See the following example code:

```
$conditions = array("Post.title" => 'This is a "Book"');
// Example usage with a model:
$this->Post->find('first', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```

Because find() actually looks for title = 'This is a \"Book\"', no result returned. I am wondering how to prevent find() from adding backslashes. Or is there any other solution?

**==fixed==**

*Actually the error occurred when I used updateAll($field, $conditions), not find(). I did not put the quote around literal values. For example, $field = array('title' => $some_title) should be $field = array('title' => "'" . Sanitize::escape($some_title) . "'") . Don't like the way CakePHP handles this though.*

Comment: I think it will work know.. You are not getting any OP

Comment: What cake version? Also, escaping those chars is correct and will still return the correct result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be mistaken. The error must be somewhere else.
The resulting SQL query does contain

```
 LIKE 'foo \"bar\"'
```

But that escaping is actually intentional.
I will still turn up the DB entry with `foo "bar"` - I just tried it myself with cake2.3/2.4.

So CakePHP is working correctly.

Comment: Yes. I was wrong. Actually the error occurs when I use updateAll($field, $conditions), not find(). I did not put the quote around literal values. For example, $field = array('title' => $some_title) should be $field = array('title' => "'" . Sanitize::escape($some_title) . "'") . Don't like the way CakePHP handles this though.

Comment: You mean that you need to manually escape for updateAll()? Well, that comes with the power of more flexability in this method (to allow literal expressions and so on). You can't have it both ways^^.

Comment: But you might also be glad to hear that for 3.x this will change (for updateAll) as the current way indeed is kind of hacky and not very secure.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked with cakePhp version 2.3.5, The double quotes are working fine, Please check below code for a Profile controller.

```
$data = $this->Profile->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Profile.type'=>'user "one"')));
pr($data);
```

Comment: @AD7six he sure can but there is no point in it for this answer (which simply duplicates mine).

Comment: @mark, For your kind information, We are here to provide correct information as much as we can, I'm not here to collect coins (reputations). I have not copied your code, I have tested the same functionality on my system then posted here as an answer.
Please come out from your narrow minded thinking.

Comment: Exactly. So what "more" correct information are you providing? Just copy and pasting others doesnt help anybody :) Kind regards.

Comment: prove that. With my best regards :) :) :) :)